# Need to access value in mongodb from react by Object ID

Tags: reactjs, mongoose, redux

I have a react project where I am using Redux. I am using mongodb on the backed. The way api returns data is with a reference id to another collection. see below:

[image: pic of database record]

The contact field has a reference to another collection called contacts. I need to extract the data from there to populate in a React application. I am using mongoose on the backend. I have attempted multiple approaches, but have been unable to get to that data. I can retrieve the objectid, but not the data in that particular collection.

Thanks,

TL

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know your code but you should use the Contact model, and query on the Contact document using the ID you mentioned,

You are using Mongoose as ORM so it should be something like

```
Contact.find({_id: THE_CONTACT_ID })
```